# Calculate probability from a Loot Table

Tags: c#, probability

I recently designed a loot table in C#, which works splendidly. I wanted to add one last thing to it though, which is a way to calculate the percent probability that an item can be picked from the table. I already know what the percent probability should be, given that I have entered all the data into an online interactive graph, I just don't know how to manually calculate it. Here is my LootTable class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace NovaEngineFramework.Framework.Probability
{
    public class LootTable
    {
        private readonly List<string> _lootTable;
        private readonly Dictionary<string , uint> _cachedLoot;
        private readonly Random _rngInstance;
        private bool _isRebuildRequired;

        public LootTable()
        {
            _rngInstance = new Random();
            _cachedLoot = new Dictionary<string , uint>();
            _lootTable = new List<string>();
        }

        public LootTable( Random random )
        {
            this._rngInstance = random;
            _cachedLoot = new Dictionary<string , uint>();
            _lootTable = new List<string>();
        }

        public void AddLoot( uint probability , string name )
        {
            if( !_cachedLoot.ContainsKey( name ) )
            {
                this._cachedLoot.Add( name , probability );
                _isRebuildRequired = true;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception( "Item: " + name + " Already Exists!" );
            }

        }

        public void DeleteLoot( string name )
        {
            if( _cachedLoot.ContainsKey( name ) )
            {
                this._cachedLoot.Remove( name );
                _isRebuildRequired = true;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception( "Item: " + name + " Did not exist!" );
            }
        }

        public double CalculateProbability(string name)
        {
            if( _cachedLoot.ContainsKey( name ) )
            {
                return 0; // Calculate the actual percent probability here
            }
            throw new Exception( "Item: " + name + " Does not exist." );
        }

        public uint CheckRarity( string name )
        {
            if( _cachedLoot.ContainsKey( name ) )
            {
                return _cachedLoot[ name ];
            }
            throw new Exception( "Item: " + name + " Does not exist." );
        }

        public List<string> CheckLoot()
        {
            return this._cachedLoot.Keys.ToList();
        }

        public void EditLoot( string name , uint newProbability )
        {
            if( _cachedLoot.ContainsKey( name ) )
            {
                this._cachedLoot[ name ] = newProbability;
                _isRebuildRequired = true;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception( "Item: " + name + " Does not exist." );
            }
        }

        public void ClearAllLoot()
        {
            this._cachedLoot.Clear();
            this._isRebuildRequired = true;
        }

        private void Build()
        {
            _lootTable.Clear();
            foreach( KeyValuePair<string , uint> pair in _cachedLoot )
            {
                for( int i = 0; i < pair.Value; i++ )
                {
                    _lootTable.Add( pair.Key );
                }
            }
            _isRebuildRequired = false;
        }

        public string NextRandomItem()
        {
            if( !_isRebuildRequired )
            {
                return _lootTable[ _rngInstance.Next( _lootTable.Count ) ];
            }
            this.Build(); // A rebuild is needed, let's go ahead and take care of it!
            return _lootTable[ _rngInstance.Next( _lootTable.Count ) ];
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my testing implementation:

```
        LootTable swordTable = new LootTable();
        swordTable.AddLoot( 1 , "Sword_Legendary_SwordOfIllimitableDemise" );
        swordTable.AddLoot( 200 , "Sword_Common_SteelGreatSword" );
        swordTable.AddLoot( 50 , "Sword_Rare_MagicImbuedLongBlade" );
        swordTable.AddLoot( 15 , "Sword_Epic_Hopesfire" );
        swordTable.AddLoot( 400 , "Sword_Trash_RustySword" );
        Console.WriteLine(swordTable.NextRandomItem());
```

And an image to help facilitate better understanding:
[image]

Here is the interactive chart link which if moused over, shows the actual % based probabilities.
[Interactive Chart](https://www.meta-chart.com/share/untitled-3786)

Visual Example of the output I am seeking:
[image]

**What is the proper way to calculate the probabilites of the loot table like the online chart does?**

**Last Edit**
For those who want the final product with answer included, here is a pastebin link of the class:

[LootTable.cs](http://pastebin.com/5rFbVn90)

Comment: Rusty sword == 400; total number of items == 666; (400 / 666) = 60.06%

Comment: @Plutonix And if someone wanted to convert the actual output from "0.600600600600601" to the more visually appealing "60.06"?

Comment: Multiply by 10000, cast to an int, then divide by 100.

Comment: @Krythic A potentially better way to print is by taking the `double x = 0.5005005050` and calling `x.ToString("P2")`, see [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/uzF9ZU)

Comment: @Bas Can you explain what P2 is, or provide a quick link so people reading this don't have to break away to google search?

Comment: @Krythic They are called 'Numeric Format Strings'. They also exist for DateTimes and TImeSpans. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add up the total number of items in `_cachedLoot`,  then divide the amount of the item in question by the total.

```
double total = _cachedLoot.Values.Sum(n => (int)n);
return _cachedLoot[name] / total;
```

(Note the cast to `double` - this is required to prevent [integer division](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3b1ff23f.aspx).)

---

If you want to return a value suitable for printing, you can modify the above slightly:

```
double total = _cachedLoot.Values.Sum(n => (int)n);
double percent = _cachedLoot[name] / total;
return Math.Round(percent * 100, 2);
```

Comment: Your update was what I was looking for. Thanks; I already accepted you as the answer!